# How does stretching the window work with tkinter's grid geometry manager?

Tags: tkinter

In tkinter, we have the `columnconfigure` and `rowconfigure` for streching the inner frame when the whole window is getting bigger.
I searched for an appropriate guide of using this two methods but I didn't find one.

I experimented by myself the stuff and learned how to use it, but I still want to hear about it from one who knows. maybe when I learned by meself I missed a detail or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When tkinter lays out a group of widgets, there may be some extra space. For example, you might have a window that is 200x200, and in it you've put four other widgets that are each 50x50.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")

f1 = tk.Frame(root, width=50, height=50, background="bisque")
f2 = tk.Frame(root, width=50, height=50, background="pink")
f3 = tk.Frame(root, width=50, height=50, background="orange")
f4 = tk.Frame(root, width=50, height=50, background="brown")

f1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
f2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
f3.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
f4.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Because we haven't configured the rows and columns, tkinter doesn't know what to do with all of the extra space, so it is left empty.

The `grid` geometry manager uses "weights" and other options to decide how to allocate unused space. By default each row and each column have a weight of zero, so each row and column is not allocated any of the extra space.

What if we want the right-most column to take up all of the extra space? We can give that column a positive non-zero weight, and `grid` will allocate all extra space to that widget.

Note that if we want extra space to be given to a widget, we configure the row or column on the *parent* widget. We aren't saying "give extra space to frame f1", we say "in the root window, give extra space to whatever is in column X".

```
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

[image]

What if we want some space to go to the left, and some to the right? The weight represents a proportion. If we want the two columns to be equal in size we can give them the same weight. It doesn't matter what the weight is, as long as they are the same.

```
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=10)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=10)
```

[image]

Since the values are proportional, we can allocate twice as much space on the right than on the left by giving the two weights a 1:2 proportion:

```
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=2)
```

We can even give a weight to an empty row or column. Normally empty rows and columns take up no space, but this is a useful technique for centering objects. For example, we can put the widgets in columns 1 and 2, and then tell `grid` to give all extra space to columns 0 and 3 to provide a centering effect:

```
f1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
f2.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="nsew")
f3.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
f4.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="nsew")

root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
```

[image]

All of the above applies to rows, too. If we move the widgets to rows 1 and 2, we can center everything by configuring all of the empty rows and columns:

```
f1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
f2.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="nsew")
f3.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="nsew")
f4.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="nsew")

root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
```

[image]

There are other configuration options besides `weight`. The complete set of options are:

- `minsize` - sets the minimum size for the row or column.
- `weight`  - sets the relative weight for apportioning any extra spaces among rows or columns
- `pad`     - sets the amount of space to use as padding (top and bottom for rows, left and right for columns)
- `uniform` - defines a uniform group. All rows (or columns) with the same value for `uniform` will have the same width or height.

The canonical documentation for how grid works is documented in the section [the grid algorithm](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/grid.htm#M32) on the [tcl/tk man page for grid](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/grid.htm#M32).